# How to define correlation name?

Tags: layout, catalog, xml

I'm getting the error with the layered navigation and custom attributes:

```
You cannot define a correlation name 'color_idx' more than once

Trace:
#0 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\lib\Varien\Db\Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'cor_idx.entity_...', Array, NULL)
#1 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\lib\Zend\Db\Select.php(336): Varien_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'cor_idx.entity_...', Array, NULL)
#2 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\lib\Zend\Db\Select.php(315): Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(Array, 'cor_idx.entity_...', Array, NULL)
#3 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php(70): Zend_Db_Select->join(Array, 'cor_idx.entity_...', Array)
#4 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php(94): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->applyFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute), '12')
#5 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\Filter\Abstract.php(91): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute->apply(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute))
#6 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\Filter\Abstract.php(73): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initFilter()
#7 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\View.php(136): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->init()
#8 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(293): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
#9 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#10 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/layer_v...', 'catalog.leftnav')
#11 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/layer_v...', 'catalog.leftnav')
#12 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#13 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#14 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#15 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#16 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#17 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#18 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 E:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 e:\WWW\capolavoro.com.br\loja\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Searching in the internet, probably blocks are duplicated but in my catalago.xml is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, 2 or more layered navigations on the page, but only one should be. The reason is that both layered navigations try to apply filter and add LEFT JOIN clause to product collection select statement using the same table alias. Any layout.xml file can add Layered Navigation block, not just catalog.xml Most probably there is some other 3rd party module adding layered navigation. And check in you app/etc/modules , most probably it can be disabled just there. [How to properly disable a module](http://www.manadev.com/blog/disable-magento-extension-module/)